# How to turn off fingerprint reader?

Tags: usb, power-management, fingerprint

How can I disable and turn off the fingerprint reader embedded in my Dell XPS 13 (7390)?

The device is a HTMIcroelectronics Goodix Fingerprint Device, USB ID 27c6:5385.

Powertop warns that it is constantly on (although I never use it) and it is unnecessarily draining the battery of the laptop.

Comment: Does this fingerprint work for you in the first place? I cannot find a driver for it in today's linux-next.

Answer (score 0):

If you never use it, see if the laptop's BIOS settings allow you to fully disable it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your case is almost the same as in mine XPS 15.

Create file `/etc/udev/rules.d/fingerprint.rules` and place there following text:

```
# Disable fingerprint reader
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="27c6", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5385", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

This disables usage of usb device with vendor and product ids defined above. Changes should be used by udev after reboot.